# How to load external js to inline javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, blogger, deferred

i have question and i hope u can help me to solved this.
i want to load external ajax recent post to inline script on my blogger, but its doesnt work..

```js
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ Defer.js('https://cdn.statically.io/gh/inpodia/cdn-labs/87852c81/rcpost.js','cPts-js',10,function(){for(var cId=document.querySelectorAll('[id^=categoryId]'),i=0;i<cId.length;++i){categoryPost({home:cId[i].getAttribute('data-home'),title:cId[i].getAttribute('data-title'),label:cId[i].getAttribute('data-label'),id:cId[i].id,time:'published',ldCl:'loaded',pstNm:6,thmbSize:600,snptLnth:120,pgn:true})};}); /*]]>*/</script>
```

i'm try to make it inline code like this

```js
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/ Defer.js('cPts-js',10,function(){for(var cId=document.querySelectorAll('[id^=categoryId]'),i=0;i<cId.length;++i){categoryPost({home:cId[i].getAttribute('data-home'),title:cId[i].getAttribute('data-title'),label:cId[i].getAttribute('data-label'),id:cId[i].id,time:'published',ldCl:'loaded',pstNm:6,thmbSize:600,snptLnth:120,pgn:true})};});
 
function _0x3905(t,e){var a=_0x1481();return(_0x3905=function(t,e){return a[t=+t]})(t,e)}function categoryPost(t){var e=201,a=200,n=183,s=686,r=686,i=199,l=173,c=198,o=231,d=685,p=640,x=197,m=198,h=675,f=647,b=674,g=673,v=184,_=133,y=709,C=714,w=643,A=690,M=684,T=705,I=731,L=877,P=451,S=438,$=453,H=509,N=501,B=458,R=916,k=941,D=902,J=468,O=926,X=469,F=438,V=470,Z=505,z=904,G=878,U=473,j=455,Q=472,q=437,E=474,K=447,Y=403,W=927,tt=454,et=499,at=894,nt=892,st=476,rt=892,it=934,lt=898,ct=853,ot=868,dt=985,pt=434,ut=403,xt=481,mt=434,ht=457,ft=436,bt=888,gt=476,vt=507,_t=870,yt=433,Ct=465,wt=856,At=893,Mt=905,Tt=476,It=466,Lt=477,Pt=885,St=858,$t=884,Ht=486,Nt=483,Bt=489,Rt=862,kt=877,Dt=911,Jt=490,Ot=527,Xt=883,Ft=874,Vt=834,Zt=872,zt=498,Gt=821,Ut=946,jt=502,Qt=504,qt=500,Et=553,Kt=435,Yt=861,Wt=891,te=863,ee=934,ae=978,ne=932,se=860,re=859,ie=879,le=897,ce=511,oe=547,de=879,pe=450,ue=400,xe=857,me=960,he=855,fe=850,be=564,ge=880,ve=937,_e=445,ye=512,Ce=465,we=421,Ae=852,Me=877,Te=518,Ie=948,Le=421,Pe=62,Se=36,$e=961;function He(t,e){return _0x3905(t- -212,e)}var Ne,Be={home:"/",title:Re(-689,-703),pstNm:6,thmbSize:600,snptLnth:150,time:"published",pgn:!0,ldCl:He(-e,-228)};function Re(t,e){return _0x3905(t- -699,e)}for(Ne in t)Be[Ne]=("undefined"==t[Ne]?Be:t)[Ne];l=Be[He(-a,-n)][Re(-s,-r)](/\/$/,"")[He(-i,-l)](/.*?:\/\//g,"//")+"/",m=Be[He(-c,-o)]&&0<Be[Re(-d,-p)].length?He(-x,-189)+Be[He(-m,-188)]:"";!function(n){var s=266,r=253,i=257,l=252,c=199,o=152,d=273,a=46,p=new XMLHttpRequest;try{p=new XMLHttpRequest}catch(t){try{p=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(t){try{p=new ActiveXObject(e(Pe,Se))}catch(t){return console[_0x3905(923-906,$e)]("Something went wrong!")}}}function e(t,e){return _0x3905(t-a,e)}p.onreadystatechange=function(){var t;function e(t,e){return _0x3905(e- -d,t)}function a(t,e){return _0x3905(e- -174,t)}4==p[a(-136,-156)]&&(200==p.status?(t=JSON[e(-s,-254)](p[e(-227,-r)]),n[e(-i,-l)](t)):"function"==typeof n[a(-c,-o)]&&n[a(-104,-152)](p))},p.open("GET",n.url,n.async),p[e(69,72)]()}({url:l+Re(-h,-f)+encodeURI(m)+Re(-b,-638)+(Re(-g,-717)==Be.time?He(-186,-157):"published")+He(-185,-156)+Be[He(-v,-_)],async:!0,success:function(t,e){var i={_0x56bcae:648,_0x653519:949,_0x2ca5ad:887,_0x359493:911,_0x5e8027:678,_0x1c7274:653,_0x17bebe:701,_0x3170bd:652,_0x424641:915,_0x2bf521:914,_0x1bbbd5:626,_0x45f88f:651,_0x488da9:648,_0x1f5830:697,_0x4ef027:647,_0x4ac953:883,_0x37c0b3:919};function a(t,e){return _0x3905(t-Le,e)}function n(t,e){return _0x3905(t- -Ie,e)}var s,r,l,c,o,d="";if(null!=document[n(-919,-L)](Be.id))if((e=t[a(P,S)])[a(452,480)]&&0!=e[a(452,431)][a($,445)]){function p(t){var a=877,e=(t=t[s(-642,-655)](0,10)).substring(0,4),n=t[s(-i._0x56bcae,-655)](5,7),t=t[r(i._0x653519,910)](8,10);function s(t,e){return _0x3905(e- -688,t)}function r(t,e){return _0x3905(e-a,t)}return[r(i._0x2ca5ad,i._0x359493),"Feb",s(-i._0x5e8027,-i._0x1c7274),s(-i._0x17bebe,-i._0x3170bd),r(i._0x424641,i._0x2bf521),s(-i._0x1bbbd5,-650),"Jul",s(-699,-649),s(-i._0x45f88f,-i._0x488da9),s(-i._0x1f5830,-i._0x4ef027),"Nov",r(i._0x4ac953,i._0x37c0b3)][parseInt(n-1)]+" "+t+", "+e}d+=(""!=Be.title?a(464,H)+Be[a(465,N)]+"</h2>":"")+a(466,B);for(var x=e.entry,m=0;m<x[n(-R,-k)];++m){for(var h=x[m],f=!1,e=0,b=h.media$thumbnail?h.media$thumbnail[n(-D,-863)]:"",g=h[n(-904,-865)].$t,v=(h.id.$t.split(a(J,482))[1][n(-900,-O)](".post-")[0],h.id.$t[a(X,F)]("post-")[1],h[a(V,Z)][1][n(-z,-G)].split(a(471,522))[0]),_=(a(472,518)in h&&0<Be[a(U,j)]?h[a(Q,q)].$t[a(434,473)](/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi,"")[a(434,425)](/<style.*?<\/style>/g,"")[n(-935,-983)](/<\!--.*?-->/g,"").split(a(E,K))[0][a(434,Y)](/(<([^>]+)>)/gi,"")[n(-935,-W)](/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")[a(454,tt)](0,Be[a(U,463)]):""),y=h.link[a(453,et)];e<y;++e)"alternate"==(s=h.link[e])[n(-at,-847)]&&(f=s.href);for(var C=!1,w=!1,A=0,M=h.category.length;A<M;++A)"Product"==h[a(476,489)][A][n(-nt,-914)]&&(C=!0),"Sponsored"==h[a(st,446)][A][n(-rt,-866)]&&(w=!0);c=b[n(-891,-it)](n(-890,-lt))?"":"-rw-e30",b=(b=h.content&&""==b?(u=/<img +(.*?)src=(['"])([^'"]+?)(['"])(.*?) *\/?>/i[n(-889,-ct)](h[n(-897,-ot)].$t))&&u[3]?u[3]:"":b)[n(-935,-dt)](/.*?:\/\//g,"//")[a(pt,ut)](/\/s[0-9]+(\-c)?/,"/s"+Be[a(xt,434)]+c)[a(mt,ht)](/\=s[0-9]+(\-c)?/,"=s"+Be[a(481,ft)]+c).replace(/\=.*w[0-9].*h[0-9].*-c+(\-c)?/,"=s"+Be[n(-bt,-910)]+c),r=h[a(gt,vt)][0]?n(-887,-937)+h[a(476,484)][0][n(-nt,-_t)]+n(-886,-864)+h.category[0].term+"' href='"+Be[a(yt,449)]+a(484,Q)+encodeURI(h[a(476,Ct)][0][a(477,U)])+"' rel='tag'></a>":"",l=h[n(-893,-wt)][1]?"<a aria-label='"+h[n(-At,-931)][1].term+n(-886,-Mt)+h[a(Tt,It)][1][a(Lt,497)]+"' href='"+Be.home+n(-Pt,-St)+encodeURI(h.category[1][a(477,483)])+n(-$t,-861):"",c="updated"==Be.time?p(h[a(447,476)].$t):p(h.published.$t),v=a(Ht,510)+(null!=v.match(/^[0-9]+$/)&&"0"!=v&&1!=C?"<a aria-label='Comments' class='cmnt' data-text='"+v+a(487,Nt)+f+n(-881,-L):"")+(1==C?"<div class='spnr'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M4.16989 15.3L8.69989 19.83C10.5599 21.69 13.5799 21.69 15.4499 19.83L19.8399 15.44C21.6999 13.58 21.6999 10.56 19.8399 8.69005L15.2999 4.17005C14.3499 3.22005 13.0399 2.71005 11.6999 2.78005L6.69989 3.02005C4.69989 3.11005 3.10989 4.70005 3.00989 6.69005L2.76989 11.69C2.70989 13.04 3.21989 14.35 4.16989 15.3Z'></path><path d='M9.5 12C10.8807 12 12 10.8807 12 9.5C12 8.11929 10.8807 7 9.5 7C8.11929 7 7 8.11929 7 9.5C7 10.8807 8.11929 12 9.5 12Z'></path></svg></div>":"")+(1==w&&1!=C?a(Bt,509):"")+a(490,526),v=""!=b?n(-878,-Rt)+f+"'><img alt='"+g+"' class='imgThm lazy' data-src='"+b+n(-kt,-Dt)+v+a(Jt,Ot):n(-876,-Xt)+v+n(-879,-919),l=r?a(494,527)+(1!=w||1==C?n(-Ft,-843)+r+" "+l+a(490,448):n(-873,-Vt))+"</div></div>":"",g="<h2 class='pTtl aTtl sml'><a data-text='"+g+n(-882,-859)+f+"' rel='bookmark'>"+g+n(-Zt,-826),_=""!=_?"<div class='pSnpt"+(1==C?a(zt,510):"")+"'>"+_+n(-879,-888):"",c=n(-_t,-Gt)+c+a(500,513)+(n(-922,-Ut)==Be[a(N,542)]?a(jt,Lt):n(-866,-893))+c+a(Qt,qt)+f+a(505,Et),o=1==Be[a(506,468)]?"<div class='blogPg'><a aria-label='View More' data-text='"+(null!=Be[a(Kt,416)]&&""!=Be.label?Be.label+n(-862,-819):n(-Yt,-Wt))+n(-882,-te)+(null!=Be.label&&""!=Be[n(-ee,-ae)]?Be.home+n(-885,-ne)+encodeURI(Be[a(Kt,433)]):Be[n(-936,-933)]+n(-se,-890))+"'></a></div>":"",d+=""!=b?'<article class="ntry'+(1==C?n(-re,-866):"")+'">':"<article class='ntry noThmb"+(1==C?" pTag":"")+"'>",d+=v+"<div class='pCntn'>"+l+g+_+c+n(-ie,-le),d+=a(ce,oe)}d+=n(-de,-870)+o,document[a(pe,ue)](Be.id)[n(-xe,-871)]=d,document[n(-919,-me)](Be.id).classList[n(-wt,-he)](Be[n(-855,-fe)]),Defer[a(515,be)](n(-853,-ge),100,n(-ve,-911),null,{rootMargin:"1px"})}else""!=Be[a(Kt,470)]?document[a(450,_e)](Be.id)[a(ye,551)]=(""!=Be[a(Ce,we)]?a(464,483)+Be.title+n(-Ae,-Me):"")+"<div class='note'>No Post was found with label '"+Be[n(-934,-956)]+"'.</div>":document.getElementById(Be.id)[a(512,563)]="<div class='note'>No Post was found.</div>";else console.log(a(Te,481)+Be.id+a(519,521))},error:function(t){function e(t,e){return _0x3905(e-614,t)}console[e(670,713)]("Failed to get Blog Feeds with status: "+t[e(y,C)]),null!=document[e(671,w)](Be.id)&&(document[e(A,w)](Be.id)[e(M,T)]=e(I,715))}})}function _0x1481(){var t=["<div class='spnr'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M13 11L21.2 2.80005'></path><path d='M22 6.8V2H17.2'></path><path d='M11 2H9C4 2 2 4 2 9V15C2 20 4 22 9 22H15C20 22 22 20 22 15V13'></path></svg></div>","</div>","<div class='pThmb'><a class='thmb' href='","' src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs='/></a>","<div class='pThmb nul'><div class='thmb'><span class='imgThm' data-text='No image'></span></div>","<div class='pHdr pSml'><div class='aNm'>","<div class='pLbls' data-text='in'> ","<div class='pLbls nSpr'><span data-text='Sponsored'></span></div>","</a></h2>"," nTag","<div class='pInf pSml'><time class='aTtmp pTtmp pbl' data-text='","' title='","time","Updated: ","Published: ","'></time><a aria-label='Read more' class='pJmp' data-text='Keep reading' href='","'></a></div>","pgn"," - View More","View More","search"," pTag","</article>","innerHTML","add","ldCl","dom",".lazy","</h2>","Sorry, Container with id '","' was not found!","log","status","<div class='note wr'>Failed to load Posts :(</div>","34iXckGA","38644jNQQMM","608439JLHtOL","2466700ePgBvC","1051495oNgpap","6DhZoTl","4537974Fvdppm","8IyOGTD","1158831rGYJCc","10660930zqtIZZ","Posts","loaded","home","replace","label","/-/","Microsoft.XMLHTTP","warn","readyState","parse","responseText","success","error","send","feeds/posts/default","?alt=json&orderby=","updated","&max-results=","pstNm","getElementById","feed","entry","length","substring","Jan","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Aug","Sep","Oct","Dec",'<h2 class="title">',"title",'<div class="blogPts ctgryPts">',"url","blog-","split","link"," Comments","content","snptLnth","<a name='more'>","rel","category","term","includes","-rw","exec","thmbSize","<a aria-label='","' data-text='","search/label/","' rel='tag'></a>","<div class='iFxd'>","' href='","#comment' role='button'><svg class='line' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><g transform='translate(2.000000, 2.000000)'><path d='M17.0710351,17.0698449 C14.0159481,20.1263505 9.48959549,20.7867004 5.78630747,19.074012 C5.23960769,18.8538953 1.70113357,19.8338667 0.933341969,19.0669763 C0.165550368,18.2990808 1.14639409,14.7601278 0.926307229,14.213354 C-0.787154393,10.5105699 -0.125888852,5.98259958 2.93020311,2.9270991 C6.83146881,-0.9756997 13.1697694,-0.9756997 17.0710351,2.9270991 C20.9803405,6.8359285 20.9723008,13.1680512 17.0710351,17.0698449 Z'></path></g></svg></a>"];return(_0x1481=function(){return t})()}!function(){var t=85,e=479,a=515,n=107,s=477,r=127,i=81,l=123,c=80,o=50,d=473,p=475,u=110,x=431;function m(t,e){return _0x3905(e- -85,t)}var h=_0x1481();function f(t,e){return _0x3905(t- -480,e)}for(;;)try{if(336811==+parseInt(m(-117,-t))*(parseInt(f(-e,-a))/2)+-parseInt(m(-n,-83))/3+-parseInt(f(-s,-472))/4+parseInt(m(-r,-i))/5*(parseInt(m(-l,-c))/6)+-parseInt(m(-o,-79))/7+-parseInt(f(-d,-p))/8*(parseInt(m(-u,-77))/9)+parseInt(f(-471,-x))/10)break;h.push(h.shift())}catch(t){h.push(h.shift())}}();/*]]>*/</script>
```

but, this post doesnt work.
*sorry, for my english*

Comment: Could you try again to explain: 1. What you are trying to load and how it should be displayed. 2. What is not working.

Comment: @Elias : im try convert that script to inline javascript to call recent post by label, but doesn't work.

i trying on my site but thast script not working.

this my site with thats code [link](https://www.inpodia.com/)

Comment: You're trying to load the JavaScript from `https://cdn.statically.io/gh/inpodia/cdn-labs/87852c81/rcpost.js` and then "paste" it into a script tag?

Comment: @Elias : Yes that's what i mean. I don't want to use external javascript

Comment: May I ask why? Because you're still using external JavaScript... you just loaded it weirdly lol. There might be a better solution for the underlying problem.